# mistakenly deleted database but recovery takes time while the company is still running

Tags: database, recovery

My friend mistakenly added an update clause and changed the company's database. The good thing is they do backup everyday at certain time. He is trying to recover. However recovery takes several hours, and the company is still producing their products and running 24/7 so he has to run the production table/database (probably from my understanding?) for current use as well during the recovery time. Problem is, during the recovery hours the new data still is being produced. so after recovery finishes, how to deal with these new data during these several hours?

I do not know if such kind of questions can be asked here. The story happens to my friend in non english country, a country without this site so I help him ask here. He is very worried.

Do you guys have any basic thought or idea about it? Personally I wonder what is the normal solution since I imagine this kind of things might happen in modern life sometimes.

Update: He told me the company produces important things and shutting down for several hours will cause huge loss

Comment: How many columns were affected in the update? How many rows were affected? How many rows does the table have in total? During recovery time are rows just added to this table, or could they be updated? If they are updated, then does it make sense from a business perspective to overwrite the update with the backup, or not? We need some context and detail here.

Comment: Obviously, the mechanics of backup and recovery depend heavily on the database.  I removed the "mysql" and "sql-server" tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the actual database being used.

Comment: Is there a programming question in here? If not that may be better asked at serverfault.com  - because there sysadmins deal with the chores of their life. Stackoverflow is only for programming questions.And dba.stackexchange deals with database particular questions. That said, your friend should be fired for gross neglect for running a statement that was untested on production.

Comment: I have taken the text from this question and posted it here - http://serverfault.com/questions/749596/mistakenly-deleted-database-but-recovery-takes-time-while-the-company-is-still-r

Answer (score 1):

Even though your questions seems broad I will still try to answer it.

1. Determine how many tables were affected
2. For each table determine exactly what records were changed and what columns where changed
3. Determine if any current transactions, stored procedures and functions or any other software has changed any of the records/rows from step 2. And how frequently are being run (they might be changing records as you read this)
4. Determine if the operations from step 3 are inconsisten because of the changes made by the incorret update. (money or any other calculation comes to mind)

After all this you should be able to determine if is best to keep running a database that was altered incorrectly and allow user and other sofware to continue updating records after they were manually altered OR if is best to let people know about a URGENT MAINTENANCE that is needed, agree with them on a MAINTENANCE WINDOW and fix the problem before the updated records and information is propagated and used to take importan decisions

My personal advice. Determine a plan to recover only the affected data to a point in time where all the records made sense and try to re-run the transactions that happend after that exact moment. Try to determine how much time will this take and agree on a **URGENT MAINTENANCE WINDOW** with the users and other software that might acceess that database.

***A database that is set to maintenance mode, where no users or other software can acccess it, runs faster and allows you to recover or undo the damage faster that if you try to keep it accesable to all user and also fix the damaged records.***

Other approach could be..(even if it does not sound very professional)...let the time pass by and if no user complains then the updated records were too old or not accesed or important to any user, but that is rarely the case and **is best to accept and fix the problem than just "hoping for the best"**

I have "reposted" this question also on ServerFault

**https://serverfault.com/questions/749596/mistakenly-deleted-database-but-recovery-takes-time-while-the-company-is-still-r**

Comment: Thank you very much about the advice. I will let him know your suggestion! By the way he told me the company produces important things and shutting down for several hours will cause huge loss.

Comment: Consider the loss of running on a database with inconsistent data for days and days and making decisions based on that information. printing invoices and sending goods based on incorrect ammouts etc, etc, etc

Comment: Mauricio, I saw you post this to serverfault.com. Much appreciated!

Comment: you are wellcome helping is adictive - http://serverfault.com/questions/749596/mistakenly-deleted-database-but-recovery-takes-time-while-the-company-is-still-r